# Gsap text animation from behind something

Tags: gsap

```js
function initLoaderHome() {
    const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: 0, yoyo: true });
gsap.set("#rectangle-svg", { transformOrigin: "50% 100%", scaleY: 0 });
  tl.to("#rectangle-svg", { duration: 1, scaleY: 1, ease: "power2.out" });
  tl.add("scaleAnimation");
  tl.to("#rectangle-svg", { duration: 1, scale: 2, ease: "ease.out(1, 0.3)" }, "scaleAnimation");
}

// Call this function when the DOM content has loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initLoaderHome);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"></script>

function initLoaderHome() {
    const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: 0, yoyo: true });
gsap.set("#rectangle-svg", { transformOrigin: "50% 100%", scaleY: 0 });
  tl.to("#rectangle-svg", { duration: 1, scaleY: 1, ease: "power2.out" });
  tl.add("scaleAnimation");
  tl.to("#rectangle-svg", { duration: 1, scale: 2, ease: "ease.out(1, 0.3)" }, "scaleAnimation");
}

// Call this function when the DOM content has loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initLoaderHome);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  

<body>
    <main>
        <svg id="rectangle-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80.13 17.71" width="200">
            <defs>
                <style>
                    .cls-1 {
                        fill: #f9f9fa;
                        stroke-width: 0px;
                    }
                </style>
            </defs>
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m6.19,17.45H0V0h6.24c1.76,0,3.27.35,4.53,1.04,1.27.7,2.24,1.69,2.93,3,.68,1.3,1.03,2.86,1.03,4.67s-.34,3.38-1.03,4.69c-.68,1.31-1.67,2.31-2.94,3.01s-2.8,1.05-4.57,1.05Zm-2.5-3.16h2.34c1.09,0,2.01-.19,2.76-.58s1.31-.99,1.69-1.82c.38-.82.57-1.88.57-3.18s-.19-2.34-.57-3.16-.94-1.42-1.68-1.81c-.74-.39-1.66-.58-2.75-.58h-2.35v11.13Z" />
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m25.78,11.88v-7.52h3.63v13.09h-3.49v-2.38h-.14c-.3.77-.79,1.38-1.47,1.85-.69.47-1.52.7-2.5.7-.88,0-1.65-.2-2.31-.6-.66-.4-1.18-.96-1.56-1.7s-.56-1.61-.57-2.63V4.36h3.63v7.69c0,.77.21,1.38.62,1.83.41.45.96.67,1.65.67.44,0,.85-.1,1.23-.3.38-.2.69-.5.92-.9.24-.4.35-.89.35-1.47Z" />
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m32.31,17.45V4.36h3.46v2.31h.15c.27-.77.73-1.37,1.36-1.82.64-.44,1.4-.66,2.28-.66s1.66.22,2.29.67c.63.45,1.05,1.05,1.26,1.81h.14c.27-.75.75-1.35,1.45-1.8s1.53-.68,2.49-.68c1.22,0,2.21.39,2.98,1.16.76.78,1.15,1.87,1.15,3.29v8.8h-3.62v-8.09c0-.73-.19-1.27-.58-1.64-.39-.36-.87-.55-1.45-.55-.66,0-1.17.21-1.54.63s-.55.97-.55,1.65v7.99h-3.52v-8.16c0-.64-.18-1.15-.55-1.53-.37-.38-.85-.57-1.44-.57-.4,0-.77.1-1.09.3s-.58.48-.76.84-.28.78-.28,1.27v7.86h-3.63Z" />
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m54.2,17.45V0h3.63v17.45h-3.63Zm3.29-3.77v-4.35h.54l4.19-4.97h4.17l-5.63,6.58h-.86l-2.4,2.74Zm4.89,3.77l-3.85-5.7,2.42-2.57,5.68,8.27h-4.25Z" />
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m74.12,17.71c-1.35,0-2.5-.27-3.47-.82s-1.71-1.33-2.24-2.33c-.52-1.01-.78-2.2-.78-3.58s.26-2.53.78-3.55,1.26-1.81,2.21-2.38c.95-.57,2.07-.85,3.35-.85.86,0,1.67.14,2.42.41.75.28,1.4.69,1.96,1.24.56.55,1,1.24,1.31,2.08.31.83.47,1.81.47,2.92v1h-11.05v-2.25h7.64c0-.52-.11-.99-.34-1.39-.23-.4-.54-.72-.94-.95s-.87-.35-1.39-.35-1.04.13-1.46.38c-.42.25-.75.59-.99,1.01-.24.42-.36.89-.37,1.41v2.14c0,.65.12,1.21.36,1.68.24.47.58.84,1.03,1.09.44.26.97.38,1.58.38.4,0,.77-.06,1.11-.17s.62-.28.86-.51c.24-.23.42-.51.54-.84l3.36.22c-.17.81-.52,1.51-1.04,2.11-.53.6-1.2,1.07-2.03,1.4-.83.33-1.78.5-2.86.5Z" />
        </svg>

    </main>






</body>
```

I want my text to animate up similar to the one on this site when it loads in. The UNFOLD svg.  [Mewsunfold](https://mewsunfold.com) I have the animation but not how it comes up from behind something. `your text`

and here is mine
[mine animation](https://josephadam.github.io/animationgsap/)

link to code
[code](https://github.com/Josephadam/animationgsap.git)

I tried chatgbt and YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several ways, here `CSS` way:

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
 .container {
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     animation: revealAnimationContainer 2s forwards;
}
 .text {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0px;
     color: #222333;
     font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
     font-size: 48px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     overflow: hidden;
     animation: revealAnimation 2s forwards;
}
 @keyframes revealAnimationContainer {
     50% {
         transform: scale(1);
    }
     100% {
         transform: scale(2.5);
    }
}
 @keyframes revealAnimation {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(100%) ;
    }
     50% {
         transform: translateY(0) ;
    }
     100% {
         transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text">BOOOOM</h1>
```

Oh I checked, you have `SVG` in your example and `GSAP`:

```js
const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1, yoyo: true });
gsap.set("#rectangle", { transformOrigin: "50% 100%", scaleY: 0 });
  tl.to("#rectangle", { duration: 1, scaleY: 1, ease: "power2.out" });
  tl.add("scaleAnimation");
  tl.to("#rectangle-svg", { duration: 1, scale: 2, ease: "ease.out(1, 0.3)" }, "scaleAnimation");
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.5/gsap.min.js"></script>

<svg id="rectangle-svg" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="rectangle" width="200" height="100" fill="#3498db"/>
</svg>
```

`Dumke SVG` update

```js
const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1, yoyo: true });
gsap.set("#rectangle", { transformOrigin: "50% 100%", y: 100 });
tl.to("#rectangle", { duration: 1, y: 0, ease: "power2.out" });
tl.add("scaleAnimation");
tl.to(
  "#rectangle-svg",
  { duration: 1, scale: 2, ease: "ease.out(1, 0.3)" },
  "scaleAnimation"
);
```

```css
* {
  background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.5/gsap.min.js"></script>


<svg
      id="rectangle-svg"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 80.13 17.71"
      width="200"
    >
      <defs>
        <style>
          .cls-1 {
            fill: #f9f9fa;
            stroke-width: 0px;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <path
        class="cls-1"
        id="rectangle"
        d="m6.19,17.45H0V0h6.24c1.76,0,3.27.35,4.53,1.04,1.27.7,2.24,1.69,2.93,3,.68,1.3,1.03,2.86,1.03,4.67s-.34,3.38-1.03,4.69c-.68,1.31-1.67,2.31-2.94,3.01s-2.8,1.05-4.57,1.05Zm-2.5-3.16h2.34c1.09,0,2.01-.19,2.76-.58s1.31-.99,1.69-1.82c.38-.82.57-1.88.57-3.18s-.19-2.34-.57-3.16-.94-1.42-1.68-1.81c-.74-.39-1.66-.58-2.75-.58h-2.35v11.13Z"
      />
      <path
        class="cls-1"
        id="rectangle"
        d="m25.78,11.88v-7.52h3.63v13.09h-3.49v-2.38h-.14c-.3.77-.79,1.38-1.47,1.85-.69.47-1.52.7-2.5.7-.88,0-1.65-.2-2.31-.6-.66-.4-1.18-.96-1.56-1.7s-.56-1.61-.57-2.63V4.36h3.63v7.69c0,.77.21,1.38.62,1.83.41.45.96.67,1.65.67.44,0,.85-.1,1.23-.3.38-.2.69-.5.92-.9.24-.4.35-.89.35-1.47Z"
      />
      <path
        class="cls-1"
        id="rectangle"
        d="m32.31,17.45V4.36h3.46v2.31h.15c.27-.77.73-1.37,1.36-1.82.64-.44,1.4-.66,2.28-.66s1.66.22,2.29.67c.63.45,1.05,1.05,1.26,1.81h.14c.27-.75.75-1.35,1.45-1.8s1.53-.68,2.49-.68c1.22,0,2.21.39,2.98,1.16.76.78,1.15,1.87,1.15,3.29v8.8h-3.62v-8.09c0-.73-.19-1.27-.58-1.64-.39-.36-.87-.55-1.45-.55-.66,0-1.17.21-1.54.63s-.55.97-.55,1.65v7.99h-3.52v-8.16c0-.64-.18-1.15-.55-1.53-.37-.38-.85-.57-1.44-.57-.4,0-.77.1-1.09.3s-.58.48-.76.84-.28.78-.28,1.27v7.86h-3.63Z"
      />
      <path
        class="cls-1"
        id="rectangle"
        d="m54.2,17.45V0h3.63v17.45h-3.63Zm3.29-3.77v-4.35h.54l4.19-4.97h4.17l-5.63,6.58h-.86l-2.4,2.74Zm4.89,3.77l-3.85-5.7,2.42-2.57,5.68,8.27h-4.25Z"
      />
      <path
        class="cls-1"
        id="rectangle"
        d="m74.12,17.71c-1.35,0-2.5-.27-3.47-.82s-1.71-1.33-2.24-2.33c-.52-1.01-.78-2.2-.78-3.58s.26-2.53.78-3.55,1.26-1.81,2.21-2.38c.95-.57,2.07-.85,3.35-.85.86,0,1.67.14,2.42.41.75.28,1.4.69,1.96,1.24.56.55,1,1.24,1.31,2.08.31.83.47,1.81.47,2.92v1h-11.05v-2.25h7.64c0-.52-.11-.99-.34-1.39-.23-.4-.54-.72-.94-.95s-.87-.35-1.39-.35-1.04.13-1.46.38c-.42.25-.75.59-.99,1.01-.24.42-.36.89-.37,1.41v2.14c0,.65.12,1.21.36,1.68.24.47.58.84,1.03,1.09.44.26.97.38,1.58.38.4,0,.77-.06,1.11-.17s.62-.28.86-.51c.24-.23.42-.51.54-.84l3.36.22c-.17.81-.52,1.51-1.04,2.11-.53.6-1.2,1.07-2.03,1.4-.83.33-1.78.5-2.86.5Z"
      />
    </svg>
```

Comment: I added the code from the second one but I cant seem to make it work and thank you for helping.

Comment: @JosephDumke Edit your post with the specific part of the code from your github that is responsible for your animation. I'll see what I can do...

Comment: So I added the code and it works but the svg instead just expands instead of looking like it came up from behind something.  Your css for the first is correct but id like to know how to do the same with gsap

Comment: Wow man you are amazing! How do you get good at knowing what to do what? Cause thats really impressive.

Comment: @JosephDumke I'm constantly learning, it's a never-ending process. If you spend enough time on it, you will gain much more knowledge than mine.